# manipulate dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I try to have the structure as follow but for multiple city and has listed the city for each day(if I do have the script to access multiple city than the issue will be solved and also the date to have included the city ... I may ask to much but I do not want to build a new package for this particular issue ... please let me know):
    [image]

can I please get help? what I do have now: the rows/index are based on date and columns based on city/country ...

Looking to have rows based on date and columns to look as picture. I do use wunderground/weather APIs. So the script below does not allow me to make any modification. I tried all and still mot the results as I'm expected, maybe the

> from wunderpython import wunderground

is the problem.

```
for city in wg['London, United Kingdom', 'Birmingham, United Kingdom', 'Leeds, United Kingdom', 'Glasgow, United Kingdom', 'Sheffield, United Kingdom', 'Bradford, United Kingdom', 'Liverpool, United Kingdom', 'Edinburgh, United Kingdom', 'Manchester, United Kingdom', 'Paris, France', 'Marseille, France', 'Lyon, France', 'Toulouse, France', 'Nice, France', 'Nantes, France', 'Strasbourg, France', 'Montpellier, France', 'Bordeaux, France', 'Lille, France', 'Grenoble, France', 'Dijon, France']:
    ds[city.name] = []
    for day in city.history['2015.08.10':'2015.08.24']:
       dailysummary = day['dailysummary'][0]        
       if dailysummary['date']['mon']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['mday']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['year'] not in x:
          x.append(dailysummary['date']['mon']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['mday']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['year'])
       ds[city.name].append(float(dailysummary['humidity']))


df = DataFrame(ds, x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer for the question in case anybody got same issue.

```
from wunderpython import wunderground
wg = wunderground.Wunderground('your_key')
from pandas import *
x = []
ds = {
    'meantempi':[],
    'maxtempi':[],
    'mintempi':[],
    'humidity':[],
    'city':[],
}

for  city in wg['London, United Kingdom','Birmingham, United Kingdom','Lyon, France']:

for day in city.history['2015.08.25':'2015.08.31']:
    dailysummary = day['dailysummary'][0]        
    if dailysummary['date']['year']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['mon']+'.'+dailysummary['date']['mday'] not in x:
        x.append(dailysummary['date']['year']+'/'+dailysummary['date']['mon']+'/'+dailysummary['date']['mday'])
        ds['meantempi'].append(float(dailysummary['meantempi']))
        ds['maxtempi'].append(float(dailysummary['maxtempi']))
        ds['mintempi'].append(float(dailysummary['mintempi']))
        ds['humidity'].append(float(dailysummary['humidity']))
        ds['city'].append(city.name)
df = DataFrame(ds, x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can [reset your index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then [set a new index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) column:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index('date')
```

Comment: Thank you. index is fine with having the dates.  I try to modify the dataframe in order have the output City/Country as column ... and values

Comment: I was thinking to have dataframe for each city but I do like to have all in one file/document (will be on schema for all at once ) or make country table and list all cities as column with index date and add humidity, temp etc ... I'm dealing for couple days with manipulating dataframe and no result what I'm expecting ...

Comment: It's still not totally clear what you want.  Do you want a separate `DataFrame` for each city?  If not, do you want the columns to be cities (like you have in your final image) or the columns to be things like humidity and temperature, like you have in your first image?

Comment: I do like to have "the columns to be things like humidity and temperature" as you said and the city to be also column ... Sorry about confusion.

Comment: In that case, what should your sample output look like?  It won't look like your final image, since that doesn't have those other columns.  Have you considered a hierarchical multi-index?

Comment: I listed on top the code what does almost provide all the fields i'm looking to get and the only think I do like to add is multiple city and the city to be listed with the date ...